# how to search through array with if statement and loop in Java Scrpit?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

How can I write code like this Python code:

```py
array = [["item1", "item2"], [1, 2]]
x = ["item1", 3]
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if x[j] in array[i]:
           # do something
```

with JavaScript?

I did write this code with JavaScript:

```js
var arr = [["item1", "item2"], [1, 2]],
     x = ["item1", 3];

for (var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
         if (x[j] in arr[i]) {
               // do something
          }
    }
}
```

But the code didn't give me the result I want.

Comment: use arr.includes(value)

Comment: change `x[j] in arr[i]` to `arr[i].includes(x[j])`

Comment: thanks it work. but is there another way like python code i made.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code and see if it works for you. In this code we are checking if there is an element which is the same in `array1` and in `array2`.

```js
var array1 = ["element1", "element2"];
var array2 = ["element0", "element2", "element3"];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    if (array1[i] === array2[j]) console.log("Element: " + array1[i] + " is in array2.");
  }
}
```